# How can I compile my code both running in win7 and win10?

Tags: c#

I want to use the toast notification of windows 10 API and it is available in windows 10.0.17763.0 or later(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp).

Therefore, I set two TFMs in my project for support windows7 also:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows7;net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

My opinion is to check the OS version. In windows7 it will send the toast notification by a custom control I made. In windows10 it will send the toast notification by origin windows10 API. Here is my code:

```
            var OSVersion = System.Environment.OSVersion;
            if (OSVersion.Version.Major == 10 && OSVersion.Version.Build > 17763)
            {
                new ToastContentBuilder()
.AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
.AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
.AddText("Andrew sent you a picture")
.AddText("Check this out, The Enchantments in Washington!")
.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                //custom toast...
            }
```

Then I met a situation, the code cannot run in earlier than windows 10.0.17763.0. that Visual Studio reports an error of `ToastContentBuilder.Show()` below
[image]

Finally, I found this tutorial by using the Conditional compilation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#support-windows-xp-windows-vista-and-windows-78-install-bases

Then I tried to use the Conditional compilation and modify my code like this:

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("Win10")]
        void ShowNotificationWin10()
        {
            new ToastContentBuilder()
    .AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
    .AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
    .AddText("Andrew sent you a picture")
    .AddText("Check this out, The Enchantments in Washington!")
    .Show();
        }
```

However, the error is still here. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try using preprocessor conditions: `#if` I don't know if the Win10 symbol will be known by the compiler on its own though, you might need to declare it in your project file for the windows 10 target

Comment: Windows 7 is out of support for some time now. Toasts aren't a Windows 10 feature though. The link you posted is for UWPs, an application type that didn't even exist in Windows 7. Windows 7 had toasts as well

Comment: Sadly out of support doesn't mean that some organisations aren't still using it daily :(

Comment: @Irwene some organizations use DOS too. That doesn't mean doing this is easy, or that the docs, libraries and samples are easy to find. You can't ask for a modern UI after **10 years**. Never mind real business consequences like losing their PCI-DSS certification, problems connecting to HTTPS sites or get breached because machines miss a few years of patches.

Comment: Windows 7 is over 10 years old. The kind of notifications shown in this page were added with Windows *8* which came out 10 years ago, almost to the day (Oct 26, 2012). There were some samples on creating toasts and shortcut lists when Windows 7 came out **13 years ago** but I can't even remember how that library was called. Microsoft used Codeplex back then and the source (even as zips) moved from site to site quite a few times

Comment: @Irwene I tried use the #if , however it doesn't work any.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos In spite it is a UWP tutorial, however it is telling about how to send a Toasts in WPF. I don't want to use the origin Toasts API in win7 but replace it with a custom control I made.

Comment: @MelonNG it works  just fine. You'll have to exclude entire sections if not files of your code though, not just signatures. The final application *can't* have a dependency on a UWP assembly when it gets compiled for Windows 7.

Comment: @MelonNG no, it's telling you how to use the Windows 10 Toast API to send a notification from any framework. `All types of apps (WPF, UWP, WinForms, console) can send notifications!` No UWP, no API, no compilation. The problem here is that your current code is referencing *libraries* and *packages* that depend on UWP. You can't solve this in code. You need to include different packages and libraries for different targets by specifying conditions in `csproj`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Previously I had an idea to make a console app to achieve the toast and it will call by the wpf app. Whereas I found I need a button in the toast to achieve ui interaction that it can do this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Could you please tell me how to include different packages and libraries for different targets by specifying conditions in csproj? Thank you.

Comment: Check [Conditional References](https://markheath.net/post/csproj-conditional-references) and the docs at [MSBuild Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022). When you see `<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net462' ">` in `csproj` it means that the contents of that section apply only if the property `TargetFramework` has the value `net462`.

Comment: It's probably a better idea to create separate projects for each target though, and use a common `Abstractions` library that defines the common interfaces and data classes. That's how the `Microsoft.Extensions.*` packages work. This way, your final application will only have to reference the correct project and use the classes from `Abstractions`. The only thing that would need to be conditionally referenced would be the final package. Even that could be pushed to a NuGet package that provides one binary for Windows 7, another for Windows 10.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried the Conditional References. Whereas, VS still reports errors. It seems I have to use the last way you said.